How to add topology to an existing feature dataset?
I have a GDB with a lot of data sets and layers(feature classes), I wrote a code to add a topology and validate a layer with that.
my code:
class Validate_Topology(object):
"""Implementation for ext_addin.button_4 (Button)"""
def __init__(self):
    self.enabled = True
    self.checked = False

def onClick(self):
    print("Starting Engine !!! ")

    # Define paths
    # gdb_path = r"C:\Users\DornicaUser\Desktop\026315_THA_Gheshlagh khanlo\026315_THA_Gheshlagh khanlo\03_Gis\02_Geodata.gdb"
    gdb_path = r'C:\Users\DornicaUser\Desktop\026315_THA_Gheshlagh khanlo\03_Gis\02_Geodata.gdb'
    feature_dataset_name = "UrbanPlanning_Topology"
    topology_name = "UrbanPlanning_Topology_Top"
    log_file_path = r"C:\Users\DornicaUser\Desktop\topology_validation_errors.txt"

    print("Step 1")

    def delete_if_exists(path):
        if arcpy.Exists(path):
            desc = arcpy.Describe(path)
            if desc.dataType == 'FeatureDataset' or desc.dataType == 'Topology':
                arcpy.Delete_management(path)
            print("Deleted existing {}".format(path))

    try:
        print("Step 2")
        # Check if geodatabase exists
        if not arcpy.Exists(gdb_path):
            raise Exception("Geodatabase does not exist: {}".format(gdb_path))

        print("Step 3")
        # Define Feature Dataset path
        feature_dataset_path = os.path.join(gdb_path, feature_dataset_name)
        delete_if_exists(feature_dataset_path)
        
        # Define the spatial reference (e.g., WGS 1984 UTM Zone 38N)
        spatial_reference = arcpy.SpatialReference(32638)  # 32638 is the code for WGS 1984 UTM Zone 38N

        # Create Feature Dataset with spatial reference
        arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management(gdb_path, feature_dataset_name, spatial_reference)
        print("Feature Dataset created successfully with spatial reference.")



        print("Step 4")
        # Define feature classes
        feature_classes = ["Roadborder_pre"]  # Update with actual feature classes

        for fc in feature_classes:
            fc_path = os.path.join(gdb_path, fc)
            if not arcpy.Exists(fc_path):
                raise Exception("Feature class does not exist: {}".format(fc_path))
            else:
                print("Feature class {} exists.".format(fc_path))

        print("Step 5")
        # Define Topology path
        topology_path = os.path.join(feature_dataset_path, topology_name)
        delete_if_exists(topology_path)
        arcpy.CreateTopology_management(feature_dataset_path, topology_name)
        print("Topology created successfully.")

        print("Step 6")
        # Add feature classes to the topology
        for fc in feature_classes:
            print("Step 6.1")
            fc_in_dataset = os.path.join(gdb_path, fc)
            print("Step 6.2")
            print(topology_path)
            print(fc_in_dataset)
            print("6.3")
            arcpy.AddFeatureClassToTopology_management(topology_path, fc_in_dataset)
            print("Step 6.4")
            print("Feature class {} added to topology.".format(fc))


        print("Step 7")
        # Add topology rules
        arcpy.AddRuleToTopology_management(topology_path, "Must Not Overlap (Area)", os.path.join(feature_dataset_path, "Roadborder_pre"))
        print("Topology rule 'Must Not Overlap (Area)' added successfully.")

        another_layer_path = os.path.join(feature_dataset_path, "AnotherLayer")
        arcpy.AddRuleToTopology_management(topology_path, "Must Be Covered By Boundary Of (Area)", another_layer_path)
        print("Topology rule 'Must Be Covered By Boundary Of (Area)' added successfully.")

        print("Step 8")
        # Validate topology
        arcpy.ValidateTopology_management(topology_path, "Full_Extent")
        print("Topology validated successfully.")

        print("Step 9")
        # Get validation errors
        errors = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(topology_path + "/Errors", ["OID@", "FeatureType", "OriginClassName", "OriginOID", "DestinationClassName", "DestinationOID", "RuleType", "RuleDescription"])
        error_messages = []

        for error in errors:
            error_message = "OID: {0}, Feature Type: {1}, Origin Class: {2}, Origin OID: {3}, Destination Class: {4}, Destination OID: {5}, Rule Type: {6}, Rule Description: {7}".format(error[0], error[1], error[2], error[3], error[4], error[5], error[6], error[7])
            error_messages.append(error_message)
            print(error_message)

        with open(log_file_path, 'w') as log_file:
            for error_message in error_messages:
                log_file.write(error_message + "\n")

        if error_messages:
            pythonaddins.MessageBox("\n".join(error_messages), "Topology Validation Results", 0)
        else:
            pythonaddins.MessageBox("No errors found.", "Topology Validation Results", 0)

    except Exception as e:
        # Handle exceptions and show error messages
        print("ACTIVATED")
        pythonaddins.MessageBox("An error occurred: {0}".format(str(e)), "Error", 0)
        print("An error occurred: {0}".format(str(e)))

Whenever I run the above code, it gives me the below error:
Starting Engine !!! 
Step 1
Step 2
Step 3
Deleted existing C:\Users\DornicaUser\Desktop\026315_THA_Gheshlagh khanlo\03_Gis\02_Geodata.gdb\UrbanPlanning_Topology
Feature Dataset created successfully with spatial reference.
Step 4
Feature class C:\Users\DornicaUser\Desktop\026315_THA_Gheshlagh khanlo\03_Gis\02_Geodata.gdb\Roadborder_pre exists.
Step 5
Topology created successfully.
Step 6
Step 6.1
Step 6.2
C:\Users\DornicaUser\Desktop\026315_THA_Gheshlagh khanlo\03_Gis\02_Geodata.gdb\UrbanPlanning_Topology\UrbanPlanning_Topology_Top
C:\Users\DornicaUser\Desktop\026315_THA_Gheshlagh khanlo\03_Gis\02_Geodata.gdb\Roadborder_pre
6.3
ACTIVATED
An error occurred: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Class must be in same feature dataset as topology.
Failed to execute (AddFeatureClassToTopology).

I can understand the above error but I can't create feature dataset for topology inside the Present layer which contains different layers.
How can I fix the bug?

You don't understand the error. Layers can't be in layers. File geodatabase only permits one level of feature dataset per feature class. Feature datasets don't exist as objects, just as a tag on a feature class. Topologies are a tag on feature classes that share a common feature dataset.
